# Error when writing \section in an external file

Tags: sectioning, write

The following MWE throws the error

> Undefined control sequence. \GenericError  ...
>
> #4  \errhelp @err@     ... l.9 \immediate\write\fich@sol {\section{Test}}
> ?

What's the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newwrite \fich@sol
\def\nameFile{example.sol}
\AtBeginDocument{ \immediate\openout \fich@sol \nameFile}
\AtEndDocument{ \immediate\closeout \fich@sol}
\immediate\write\fich@sol {\section{Test}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prevent expansion while you write to the file, you can do so by prefixing `\section` with `\string` or `\noexpand` (the difference is small, but with `\string` you'll get no space after `\section` in the output, while with `\noexpand` you'll get `\section {Test}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newwrite \fich@sol
\def\nameFile{example.sol}
\AtBeginDocument{ \immediate\openout \fich@sol \nameFile}
\AtEndDocument{ \immediate\closeout \fich@sol}


\begin{document}

Test
\immediate\write\fich@sol {\string\section{Test}}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, I have an issue with special characters. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583210/8323